# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vonage.webrtc.voiceengine.BuildInfo"

Tags: android, kotlin, opentok

I tried to install opentok library using dependencies but it's filed so I downloaded a library and added it inside the libs folder after that I got this error

> W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.vonage.webrtc.voiceengine.BuildInfo" on path: DexPathList[[zip
> file         "/data/app/com.bluecrunch.dareyourbody-buQZ-
> eZUzOFFJdSCL_Ms_g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/-buQZ-
> eZUzOFFJdSCL_Ms_g==/lib/arm64,
> -buQZ-eZUzOFFJdSCL_Ms_g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,     /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64, /prets/lib64]]
> W/System.err:     at
> dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    W/System.err:
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> W/System.err:     at com.opentok.android.Utils.init_otc_engine(Native
> Method)    W/System.err:     at
> com.opentok.android.Utils.initOtcEngine(Unknown Source:5)
> W/System.err:     at com.opentok.android.Session.(Unknown
> Source:67)    W/System.err:     at
> com.opentok.android.Session$Builder.build(Unknown Source:25)

Comment: which version of the opentok library are you using?